# Getting garbage at end of NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to pass some string to a NSString var, but i"m getting garbage at end of string.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    mySegue = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",mySegue);
    if ([[self category] isEqualToString:@"restaurantes"]) 
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"restaurante" sender:self];
    else if ([[self category] isEqualToString:@"bares"]){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bar" sender:self];
    }
    else if ([[self category] isEqualToString:@"cafes"]){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"cafe" sender:self];
    }
}
```

The NSSlog outputs the right string, but the debug area shows garbage at the end of the string. as shown in image below. see mySegue var and the output from nslog.
[debug http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h134/automud/ScreenShot2013-01-21at35430PM.png](http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h134/automud/ScreenShot2013-01-21at35430PM.png)

cell.textlabel.text is set like this

```
cell.textLabel.text = [restauranteArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

restauranteArray is set like this

```
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"RestaurantesList" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        self.restaurante = dictionary;
        self.restauranteArray = [self.restaurante allKeys];
```

Witch comes from this plist

[plist http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h134/automud/ScreenShot2013-01-21at42638PM.png](http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h134/automud/ScreenShot2013-01-21at42638PM.png)

So, why am I getting this garbage at the end of the string?

EDIT--------------
I use the var to pass to the next viewcontroller

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"restaurante"]){

        PCDetailViewController *detailController = (PCDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        detailController.estabelecimento = mySegue;
        detailController.tipo = @"Restaurante";
    }
}
```

on the next viewcontroller on viewDidLoad I have this

```
    self.estabelecimentoArray = [self.estabelecimentoDic objectForKey:estabelecimento];
```

and when I try objectForKey:estabelecimento I get nothing because the strings doesn't match

Edit--------------

Here you can see that the output is Capitão Grill, but the var is Capitão Grill Grill
[garbage http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h134/automud/ScreenShot2013-01-21at50213PM.png](http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h134/automud/ScreenShot2013-01-21at50213PM.png)

Comment: Right click your pList in Xcode and go to Open > As Source Code.  Paste a pic of the actual XML.

Comment: Ok I edited the question with the new pic

Comment: I've seen this before as well, though not sure the cause. I've come to the conclusion the data is sound, but the XCode debugger is simply confused.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that the debugger is confused by the non-ASCII character at the end of the string.  The NSLog appears to be correct, and that would be the "authority".

Comment: The thing is, mySegue is passed to the next viewController. and htat string is compared to another string and is returning false. I'm editing the question with some more stuff.

Comment: I don't even see where/what the garbage is.

Comment: Where is the category set?  I suspect that this doesn't have anything to do with the garbage issue.